# Is there something like source maps for CSS?

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, source-maps

I'm dynamically adding CSS tags to a page with jQuery:

```
$('<style type="text/css"/>').text(css).appendTo(document.head);
```

When viewed in the Chrome Developer Tools, all of the CSS appears as "localhost", which isn't always helpful:

[image]

Is there anything like Source Maps for CSS which would let me identify the source of the CSS to the debugger?

Comment: Just curious and not meaning to make you explain your whole project, but why exactly are you adding in stylesheets this way?  Adding the stylesheets conditionally before the templates are served would surely solve this issue, as well as cause far less re-rerendering work required by the browser when dynamic CSS like this is injected...

Comment: Chrome does a good job of identifying remote, page and element level CSS. localhost is just your default page and probably the correct source of your dynamically added CSS. I'm with @joeellis however, I don't like the idea of creating CSS on the fly. It should be added to the response stream as early as possible so the browser can use it to render later rather than have to constantly re-render elements based on dynamically added changes.

Comment: @joeellis It's a plugin system for a larger framework. Plugins can do things like add CSS and JavaScript to the page which gets evaluated after the main app is initialized but before it starts its main loop. Weird glue code requires weird glue-ey solutions :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a sourceURL to the inline style tag as you add it.

```
/*@ sourceURL=mystyles.css */
```

This will give that inline style tag a temporary name that will be used inside of the DevTools for navigation.

Comment: Is there to make it work with inline source maps? E.g.
`
<style>
body { color: red; }
/*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9.. */
</style>
`

Answer (score 0):

It is identifying the source of the CSS. It only shows up as localhost because the source of the style is from the internal javascript on your localhost homepage. if you click the link to the rule location, it should still take you to the in-line javascript that dynamically set your style.

As for a source map, have you tried expanding the "Computed Style" section and then expanding the specific style with which you want to view the inheritance hierarchy?